# Duplicate Plank Icon for Custom Launcher

Tags: plank, desktop

I've created a custom .desktop file to launch an Android Emulator bash script file. I've successfully gotten the file to launch the emulator but I get two icons in Plank. I've read about this happening with Chrome and needing to add StartupWMClass= but I'm not sure what to put after the =

Here is my .desktop file that launches my bash script shown below that...

[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Android Emulator
Comment=Android Emulator
Exec=/home/elementary/Tools/Emulator/emulator.sh
Icon=/home/elementary/Tools/Emulator/emulator_48.png
Categories=Utility
Terminal=false

---

## !/bin/bash

cd ~/Android/Sdk/tools
./emulator -avd Emulator -gpu on -qemu -m 2048 -enable-kvm &

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/367396/what-represent-the-startupwmclass-field-of-a-desktop-file

I needed to identify what to place on a StartWMClass and the command xprop WM_CLASS provided that.